# Ionic Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button

I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my HTML.

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="0" checked="{{value0}}"/>
    <label>Standard</label>

    <br>

<input type="radio" ng-value="1" checked="{{value1}}"/>
        <label>Hidden</label>
```

and this is my js. What I do is call an endpoint. if it returns 0, then standard should be checked. If it returns 1 then hidden should be checked.

```
$http.get(www.website.com, {"headers": {authorization: strToken}}).success (function(response)
    { 

        console.log (angular.toJson (response))


        if (response==0)
        {
            $scope.value0=true
            console.log ('value is 0')

        }
        else if (response==1)
        {
            $scope.value1=true
            $scope.value0=false
            console.log ('value is 1')

        }


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do following in JS:

```
$http.get(www.website.com, {"headers": {authorization: strToken}}).success (function(response)
    { 
        $scope.app= {}; //Blank object to interact with DOM
        $scope.app.value0 = false;
        $scope.app.value1 = false;
        console.log (angular.toJson (response))


        if (response==0)
        {
            $scope.app.value1=false;
            $scope.app.value0=true; //put your value in object which we created
            console.log ('value is 0')

        }
        else if (response==1)
        {
            $scope.app.value1=true; //put your value in object which we created
            $scope.app.value0=false; //put your value in object which we created
            console.log ('value is 1')

        }


})
```

and in your HTML:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="0" checked="{{app.value0}}"/>
    <label>Standard</label>

    <br>

<input type="radio" ng-value="1" checked="{{app.value1}}"/>
        <label>Hidden</label>
```

Or you can use like this also without brackets:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="0" checked="app.value0"/>
    <label>Standard</label>

    <br>

<input type="radio" ng-value="1" checked="app.value1"/>
        <label>Hidden</label>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you for trying but it doesn't work. Instead it selects both of them.